# Facebook Ads API Insights Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api, facebook-insights

I'm encountering a strange issue when it comes to retrieving data from the php facebook ads api. In our account, we are running several types of ad programs, one being a page like boost campaign. I am able to get several page likes stats, however after about 17 calls to the api, I receive the following error. Any ideas as to what's going on here. It's a strange error message, because I'm able to retrieve actions in every call prior (17 calls).

```
Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'actions is not a field of FacebookAds\Object\Insights' in C:\wamp\www\api_integration\facebook_ads\vendor\vendor\facebook\php-ads-sdk\src\FacebookAds\Object\AbstractObject.php on line 56
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @Jay thank you for the follow up. Yes I did figure it out. I was using a silly method of accessing the objects. Looked through some of the documentation and was able to take care of it.

Comment: Add your findings as answer or delete your question if it's an implementation issue specific to you

Comment: yep, please add an answer to your question, it'll help (I'm encountering the same issue right now)

Answer (score 0):

To me, this is an issue with the sdk.

Retrieving data of the same type do not have to success sometimes and throw some other based on the presence of an attribute.

I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/issues/130) and offered [a pull request](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/pull/131).